# matlab find edge Undefined function 'power' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Tags: matlab, edge-detection

my source code:

```
function void = find_edge()
path_io = 'io_find_edge\';
format = '.jpg';
list_img = ['Parent_006.jpg'; 'Parent_007.jpg'; 'Parent_008.jpg'; 'Parent_009.jpg'; 'Parent_010.jpg'];
list_filter = {'sobel', 'canny', 'prewitt', 'roberts', 'log'};

for index = 1:size(list_img)
    img_name = list_img(index, 1:10);
    img = rgb2gray(imread([path_io img_name format]));
    for filter = list_filter
        imwrite(edge(img, filter), [img_name '_' filter format], 'jpeg');
    end
end
```

error:
Undefined function 'power' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in edge (line 420)
        cutoff = (thresh).^2;

Error in find_edge (line 15)
        x = edge(img, filter);

thanks!

Comment: You show us an error inside a function we don't know. Please post relevant code. `filter` is an in-built function, don't use it as a variable name! Maybe that already solves the problem. Where do you define it actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the inner for loop, `filter` will be a cell with only one entry containing the current filter name. Still it is a cell array, so the `edge` function returns an error. You will can access the content of `filter`, i.e. the string with the current filter name, by using `filter{:}`.

I think you also have an error in constructing the file name. I assume you want to use `filter` instead of `list_filter` to create the filename, right?

Thus:

```
imwrite(edge(img, filter{:}), [img_name '_' filter{:} format], 'jpeg');
```

PS: as @thewaywewalk remarked in a comment, `filter` is the name of a function. It is not advisable to use it as a variable name, as then the `filter` function won't work anymore. I suggest to rename it to e.g. `current_filter`.